# Javascript working in Chrome, but not IE11

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Using the following code in IE:

```
function clearfields()
{
billing_phone.value="";
billing_email.value="";
billing_first_name.value="";
billing_last_name.value="";
} window.onload = clearfields
```

Working in Chrome, Firefox but not IE11. Console in IE says "'billing_phone' is undefined", but the billing_phone is definitely defined. Onload problem? I'm using this in Wordpress, so that should probably be taken into account.

Comment: _"Console in IE says "'billing_phone' is undefined", but the billing_phone is definitely defined"_ - well then show us where.

Comment: You are relying on bad coding practice to reference form fields. Refernce the element by Id with getElementById or use form reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should be referencing the element correctly.

It is either by `id="billing_phone"`

```
document.getElementById("billing_phone").value="";
```

or by `name="billing_phone"`

```
document.formName.billing_phone="";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("formId").billing_phone.value="";
```